# Get start time and end time of a Span when using Spring cloud sleuth

Tags: instrumentation, spring-cloud-sleuth

We are using Cloud sleuth to instrument microservices that use PubSub (using spring cloud stream binder). Currently PubSub traces are not getting propagated automatically to GCP cloud trace. So we are writing the traces using google cloud trace service client which internally calls trace v2 API. For each span we also have to set start time and end time.
In order to handle a retry scenario, I need to get start time of span. Is there a provision to get start time and end time of span? Tracer object does not have method to return these values. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get them from a `Span`. You can get them only when the span has been finished. If you're using Brave as the Tracer implementation you can create your own `SpanHandler` and you can access the information from the `MutableSpan` instance.